# Monitoring rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, monitor, rake-task

I have a rake task running daily at a specified time, I just want a alert email(or sms) when it fails (or even the entire rake task hangs or even the server hangs). Earlier I was using AlertGrid, I will send a signal to alertgrid at the end of the rake task, and configured alertgrid in such a way to notify me in the absence of signal, but I cannot continue with it alertgrid now, does anyone know any alternative approach for this problem?

Or any other method to monitor rake task and intimate unsuccessful operation of rake task?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best approach but you *could* have your rake task relegate the actual job to Resque and just schedule your rake task via a cron job.

Resque has a very nice web-admin that shows off all failed jobs per queue; as for notification you could possibly modify Resque to send out an email (and/or process a different job to send out texts via the API of whatever SMS-provider you use).